# Deploy and Upgrade pods in Namespace

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, microservices, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am working in a Java Springboot microservice-based complex application that comprises 30 services.

All are containerized and from ECR, services are deployed inside the Kubernetes namespace in AWS.

Every time, the namespace is purged and all services are re-deployed.
How can I update only one service inside a namespace…is it possible to do that kind of deployment.

Can someone please Any sample configurations using helm or any useful links

Answer (score 1):

> How can I update only one service inside a namespace…is it possible to do that kind of deployment.

If you are executing `helm upgrade` it should only update the resources which are updated.

you need to understand how does Helm packs the resources, `helm` is using `Kustomization` so if you are updating `Secrets`, `ConfigMap` etc it will generate new names for those resources.

As a side effect, it will "change" the `Deployment` and the results will be a "full" deploy of all the resources

---

[image]

Comment: What are the good practices to deploy the helm charts per service